# Text from pdf non-english characters

Tags: php, regex, pdf, pdftotext

I'm trying to use pdf2text library from here:

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

My pdf contains data in Czech language, and the library is having problems with some characters, ie.:

ř is replaced by Y
Ž is replaced by }
Kč is replaced by K\r
.. etc.

But some of them are okay, like: í, ú, Ý.

Replacing the regexp

> [0-9a-f]

with

> [0-9\x01-\x7F]

in the library gave me no results at all (I'm not good with regexp to be honest). Replacing string functions with mb_ ones also makes no difference

Example data:

> Kupující: anna123 - Anna Tova; Příjemce: Anna Tova, Jezborice 123, 530 02 Pardubice; Kontaktní údaje:
>   AnnT@seznam.cz, 7211111
>   A1244 SVET_MODNI STYLOVÝ SVETR V.42-POUŽITÉ (5209214093)

gives me the result of:

> Kupující: anna123 - Anna Tova; PYíjemce: Anna Tova, Jezborice 123, 530 02 Pardubice; Kontaktní údaje: AnnT@seznam.cz, 7211111 A1244 SVET_MODNI STYLOVÝ SVETR V.42-POU}ITÉ (5209214093)

Thanks

Comment: probably a font problem. the pdf is in font X, where char # (say) 1234 is `ř`, then you print it out in another font, where char #1234 is `Y`

Comment: You need a proper library to read text, just looking at the content stream won't do, there are other tables that must be used to map the code points to characters.

Comment: Any chance to "see" the PDF in question?

Comment: You can look at it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzj5CeT_gWHJN1JOWnZjRW1NSjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Not a solution, but what result are you trying to achieve? Based on that there might be a way not to use specific special characters. For example `[\S*]` matches word with special characters in it.